# What means -ms-transform: rotate(deg); in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    .a {
      width: 150px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: yellow;
      -ms-transform: rotate(22deg); /* IE 9 */
      transform: rotate(20deg); 
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>The transform Property</h1>

    <h2>transform: rotate(20deg):</h2>
    <div class="a">Hello World!</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

In the css -ms-transform:rotate(20deg) cant any change in the code . But in the examples it is used to code. What is the use of that line in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transform property applies a 2D or 3D transformation to an element. This property allows you to rotate, scale, move, etc., elements. And here, the `-ms-transform` property is used so that your CSS can also be applied in Internet Explorer. So, if you want to see the change, then open it in Internet Explorer, and you will be able to see the change.

Exact phrase from MDN Web DOCS: Microsoft applications such as Edge and Internet Explorer support a number of special Microsoft extensions to CSS. These extensions are `prefixed` with `-ms-`.

You can study more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Microsoft_Extensions